# How to reduce the padding from the eCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, echarts

I am using `echarts` for visualizing some data in my web-application. I am using basic gauge chart for the visualization. If you notice the image below, there is too much padding in the chart. I would like to remove those padding and ideally have the chart occupy 100% of the space within the container?

Here is the javascript code:

// Setup chart
            gauge_basic_options = {

```
            // Add title
            //title: {
            //    text: 'Server resources usage',
            //    subtext: 'Random demo data',
            //    x: 'center'
            //},

            // Add tooltip
            tooltip: {
                formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c}%"
            },

            // Add series
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Total Invoices',
                    type: 'gauge',
                    center: ['50%', '55%'],
                    detail: {formatter:'{value}%'},
                    data: [
                        {value: 50, name: 'Total Invoices'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
```

Any idea how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In the gauge you also can control the padding with chart [radius](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-gauge.radius). By default radius is 75% and for fill space completely you need to set new value, example:

```js
option = {
  series: [{
  name: 'Total Invoices',
  type: 'gauge',
  radius: '100%', // this
  center: ['50%', '50%'],
  detail: {formatter:'{value}%'},
  data: [ {value: 50, name: 'Total Invoices'} ]
}]
  };

var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.7.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width:300px; height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can [specify the spacing](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid.left) of the `grid` from each edge with a value, in pixels, or percentage:

```
var option = {
  grid: {
    left: '10%',
    right: '10%',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
}
```

However, I would warn against using `0` for `top` or `bottom` when you have hidden the x-axis.  Part of the chart line can get clipped and will look a different thickness if it runs along the base of the axis.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the bar chart for the same issue. Added below in options.
This solved it.

```
grid: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding is automatically adjusting based on the size of the div.

Eg: Below div will use the whole page and renders the gauge with plenty of whitespaces

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100vw;height:100vh;"></div>
```

And below one would be a compact one

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100vw;height:100vh;"></div>
```

Check this fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/athishayd/x5Lc3mr6/1/

*I would like to remove those padding and ideally have the chart occupy 100% of the space* - This would hamper the gauge's aesthetics.

Comment: Your width should be 100vw